How can I create Deposit and withdrawal Backend in Nextjs?
I'm Building a nextjs project. I want to create a deposit and withdrawal page for only USDT Trc20. In deposit page page the user will only provide the transaction Id. How can I verify that transaction Id that did user transfered to my USDT trc20 address or not and How much USDT the user transfered. I want Help in this to Know That which library or method should I use to achieve my goal. Please Help
I tried using tronweb but it didn't really worked. When my backend file checks the transaction Id it gives the TRX amount but I want the USDT token amount.
